# UICollectionView setting the last cell a section

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently working on a carousel view which works with a `UICollection` which has this form:

```
[cell1][cell2][cell3] ... [cell n][ + ]
```

So my `UICollection` has only one section.

Each cell has content except the last one. The last cell (`n+1`) have a plus button inside which allows the user to insert a new cell in the carousel.

I wrote this code into the datasource method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to know if the cell at the current index path is the last cell:

```
if ([indexPath section] == sectionsAmount - 1 && [indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1) {
    FormationCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellFormation" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell.
}
```

The last cell of my carousel is okay, but when I scroll horizontally in my carousel, **the last cell is also generated at some index of the carousel, and replaces my other cells during the scroll**. I think it's a problem on the reusable cell. Can anyone help me please?

This is what I want:

```
[cell1][cell2][cell3] ... [cell n][ + ]
```

After init carousel I have that:

```
[cell1][cell2][cell3] ... [cell n][ + ]
```

So it's okay, but when I scroll in my carousel I have this bug:

```
[cell1][ + ][ + ] ... [cell n][ + ]
```

The last cell is cloned at some positions.

Comment: are those 2 exactly equal dequeue calls really there or just a misstype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should override `prepareForReuse` method on your cell subclass, and do any configuration cleanup there, like resetting the UI and cell states.

[Docs reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse)

*Update*

Does the [ + ] cell uses the same class as the [cell n] cells?
If it does, then you are not clearing the state before reusing (and thus, you should clear it on the `prepareForReuse` method). If you are, then you may be using the same cell identifier for both.

Comment: Can you give me an example ? I don't see what I need to clear in the prepareForReuse method.

Comment: Do you have any states you set on the cell? do you set any variables in it? Texts? images? `prepareForReuse` runs right when dequeuing the cell, so you would use that to set the image nil, set the state to default (or whatever default state you defined), remove texts etc.

You use `prepareForReuse` to set the cell as if it was just created.

Comment: Yes, in fact each cells loads their content from an NSMutableArray which contains many NSDictionnary. A cell is composed by a title, a subtitle, and a description. The first cell loads its data from the first NSDictionnary, the second cell from the second dictionnary etc...

So if I understand :  I need to resetting the cell as it shoud be ?

Comment: Yes they are using the same class. In fact all my cells have the same identifier which is @"CellFormation" because I have created the custom cell from the storyboard and add an identifier to it.

Comment: So how do you say to the cell that "hey, you there will be the [ + ] cell"? what property you set?
That would be the property you should set back in the `prepareForReuse`
(*Update*  yes, you should reset any property that the dictionary configures in the `prepareForReuse` to be empty or nil.)

Comment: Instead of create a cell by setting :
mCell.title.text = @"a text";
mCell.subtitle.text = @"a subtitle"; Etc.

I create a custom view that I made, and I place this view inside my cell : [cell addSubview:myCustomView]; This custom view contains an image, and a text. So I need to clear this custom view ?

Comment: Thank you really, you solved my problem, very good answer. I was looking for a solution since a week. I only do that : 

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [self.formationAdd removeFromSuperview];
}

In my customCell.m and it works, I remove the view which was inside my cell when the cell will be reused. Thank you so much !

Comment: you should accept the answer to tag this as answered/resolved =)